# Provide type-class when implementing/override method

Tags: scala, typeclass

I would prefer to work more with type-classes but having some issues:
Given the following interface

```
trait Processor[A] {
  def process[B](f: A => B): Processor[B]
}
```

I have an implementation that needs an `Ordering[A]` for some other reasons. Hence the method `process` needs an `Ordering[B]` to construct a `Processor[B]`.The following is what I would like to do, but it does obviously not work:

```
class Plant[A, OA <: Ordering[A]] extends Processor[A] {
  def process[B:Ordering](f: A => B): Processor[B] = null // Plant[B, OB <: Ordering[B]]
}
```

How can I provide the `Ordering[B]` for the implementation of `process`?

I know the reason for this is, that `Ordering[A]` is passed as an implicit second argument. I don't know but shouldn't there be special support for type-classes in Scala similar to Haskell to recognize what I want (only allow `B`s that have an `Ordering`) in the implementation above without this "workaround"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and this shouldn't work at all. Given your defnition of `Processor`, this code will compile:

```
val processor: Processor[Int] = foo() // foo() is some function that returns a Processor
processor.process[Object](x => new Object())
```

Now if `foo` is actually implemented as

```
def foo() = new Plant[Int]()
```

then its `process` method won't work with `B = Object`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but perhaps you could make `Processor` generic on the context bound?

```
trait Processor[A, Bound[_]] {
  def process[B: Bound](f: A => B): Processor[B, Any]
}

class Plant[A: Ordering] extends Processor[A, Ordering] {
  def process[B: Ordering](f: A => B) = ???
}
```